# PHPMailer sending email twice

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I've setup a very basic example using `phpmailer`, and it's working, except it sends the email **twice**. The script is only being executed once, but I'm always getting 2 separate emails in the destinatary email (i know because the subject changes the `rand()` value each time). Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

This is my current code:

```
<?php
# phpmailer
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

# vendor
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

# create mail object
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    # smtp configuration
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'postmaster@example.com';
    $mail->Password = '*************';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS; // for 587
    $mail->Port = 587;

    # from
    $mail->setFrom('postmaster@example.com', 'My name');

    # to
    $mail->addAddress('someone@example.com', 'My friend');

    # content
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'This is a test: '.rand();
    $mail->Body = '<strong>Hello!</strong> This is a test';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Hello! This is a test';

    # send email
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Successfully sent!';
}
catch(phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} 
catch(exception $e) {
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
die();
```

Comment: Clearly the script is executed twice, and the evidence is that you get two different numbers in the subject, each time you think you execute the script once. Or are you saying that you get two emails, with the same number, each time you execute the script once? Note that it's unclear, from what you write, which of these two cases is actually happening.

Comment: [Read the docs on this subject](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Diagnosing-email-sending-twice-(or-more)).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I get two emails with different subjects. The script is only fired once, and I only get one `echo 'Successfully sent!';` at the end (with a `die();` just in case), still I get two emails.

Comment: @Synchro I went through a similar list, and I'm not falling in any of those cases.

Comment: OK, so the evidence seem to support the idea that the script is executed twice. This is now what you should check, to make sure this is the case. But how? If you use a database you could store the subject line in the database, every time the script is executed. Or you could write something to a log file, or even (ab)use [the PHP log system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php). I'm sure you find two database entries or logs for every time you think the script is executed once. So then the question becomes: Why is the script executed twice?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware after retesting this issue, i see that the 2nd email is being sent with an additional value in $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] (in this case https://example.com/sw.js which is the Service Worker). I guess the browser itself executes the function again because it was being called in the SW behind curtains.